# Какие языки программирования компилируются в исполняемый файл?

Tags: компиляция, любой-язык

А именно чтобы эти языки были для Windows (exe) и Linux (elf).
Плюс чтобы была работа с базовыми функциями (Сокеты, cmd(Windows), ...)
Кроме *c++*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Компиляция или интерпретация — не свойство самого языка. К практически любому языку можно построить компилятор, генерирующий нативный для данной операционки файл. Исключение составляют, пожалуй, лишь языки, в которых исходный текст ссылается на себя во время выполнения (например, если язык содержит `goto` на номер строки, вычисляемой во время выполнения — и то в этом случае можно построить таблицу переходов).

Другое дело, что для поддержки сложных фич (`dynamic` в C#, `eval`) вам может понадобиться доступность компилятора в системе во время выполнения.

Большой список можно посмотреть, например, [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language).

(Не все они поддерживают, например, работу с сокетами без внешних библиотек. Ну так C++ тоже работает с ними лишь через библиотеки операционной системы.)

Comment: С данным утверждением я не согласен. Синтаксис компилируемых языков специально сделан таким, чтобы компиляция была максимально эффективной (и давала эффективый, быстрый и компактный код), из-за чего многие вещи, которые кажутся элементарными в интерпретируемых языках (вроде полной рефлексии), в компилируемых изначально недоступны.

Comment: @gbg: C# — полностью компилируемый язык, но рефлексия в нём есть.

Answer (score 8):

Технически, требование **одного исполняемого файла** очень слабое и под него подходит целая куча языков.

Вы не наложили никаких ограничений на то, что в этот исполняемый файл будет входить. А туда можно засандалить столько, что запустить можно будет программу на любом языке. К тому же, надо разделять **язык** от **реализации языка**. Для любого языка можно, теоретически, сделать реализацию, подходящую для любой из групп ниже. Разделение между группами, кстати, довольно размытое. Увидите.

Я перечислю несколько ярких примеров.

#### Хорошие случаи

Языки, которые изначально разрабатывались для компиляции в нативный код. Исходный код в результате обработки типичным тулчейном языка превращается в исполняемый файл, хотя, для любых нетривиальных задач, с зависимостями от ОС и/или динамической линковки с чем-нибудь.

- **С**:  "почти С++" (на самом деле нет), но всё-таки другой язык. Подходит по очевидным причинам.
- **Rust**: достаточно новый язык в одной нише с С, в семантику и компилятор которого встроен хороший кусок *статического анализа* на предмет ошибок, которые в большинстве языков себя проявят только во время работы программы.
- **Haskell**: *радикально* отличающийся от вышеперечисленных язык с упором в функциональный стиль. Монады, вывод типов, иммутабельность "и много других страшных слов".

#### Необычные случаи

Языки, у которых существенная часть бинарника не относится к скомпилированному коду, а служит исключительно поддержкой для языка. Но это, как ни крути, часть бинарника!

- **Go**: то, что программы на нём компилируются в одиночные бинарники (и крупные!), часто подаётся, как одна из основных особенностей. Может сбить с толку то, что он использует сборщик мусора, но этот сборщик вкомпиливается в исполняемый файл, так что технически... подходит.
- **Haxe**: исходный код на этом языке можно скомпилировать в целый ряд языков (это основная особенность) и запустить родным для каждого из них способом. В контексте вопроса из этого ряда интересует только C++, для него этот способ: сборка в один исполняемый файл. Тут та же история, сборщик мусора вкомпилирован в исполняемый файл и не требует рантайма.
- **Crystal**: язык, во многом основанный на семантике и синтаксисе Ruby, но претерпевший ряд модификаций с целью поддержать статическую типизацию (вывод типов всё-таки не всегда спасает) и компилируемость вообще. Тоже со сборщиком мусора, который тоже вкомпиливается в бинарник.
- **Scheme** ([Gambit](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)): транспилятор Scheme (это [лисп](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF) такой) в C с набором поддерживающих функций.

#### Тяжёлые случаи

Языки, код на которых в бинарнике представлен не нативным кодом и выполняется на рантайме, который, технически, может размещаться в том же исполняемом файле.

- **Lua**: наверное, первый по популярности встраиваемый язык. Есть даже LuaJIT, который уже во время выполнения делает из Lua нативный код.
- **Ruby**: у него много реализаций, но *mruby* приспособлен для встраивания. Чтобы минимизировать требования к платформе, сделана возможность его разделить на компилятор в байт-код и исполнитель байт-кода.
- **Python**: можно запаковать интерпретатор вместе с кодом программы ([PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)'ом, например). Фактически получается, что код исполняемого файла не содержит пользовательского кода, а распаковывает его и запускает.

Comment: Прибавьте C#. Под телефоны/Win10 есть нативная компиляция, не требующая даже установки .NET Framework. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn584397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @VladD вообще ответ надо бы приправить ссылками на реализации, о которых я тут говорю. .NET Native, на вид, относится к группе **необычных случаев**?

Comment: Ну, у меня ж есть ссылка. А так — Visual Studio 2015, доступно бесплатно. Насчёт необычности не уверен, они это продвигают в мейнстрим :)

Comment: @VladD просто я описываемые случаи разбил на три группы, снабдив "грубым определением". Вы б к какой отнесли его? :)

Comment: Как пока ещё необычный случай, мигрирующий в сторону хорошего. :) Впрочем, мне не очень нравится требование, чтобы не было отдельного рантайма. Для C целый линукс есть по сути рантайм, так что для справедливости надо выкинуть C тоже. То, находится рантайм в каталоге `/bin` или `C:\Windows\.NET Framework` — мелкие подробности.

Comment: @VladD потому определения и грубые. Выше уже обсуждалось, что "если рантайм есть везде, его наличие обсуждать смысла мало".

Answer (score 5):

В современности, если выкинуть всякую эзотерику, вроде [компиляции питона в бинарник при помощи швабры и такой-то матери](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python), остаются:

1. С++
2. С
3. Pascal
4. Fortran (на кластерах он еще жив).

**Дальше - выжимка из ответов на комментарии, читать исключительно ради лулзов:**

Также имеются два популярных языка - хипстерский Go, у которого на эмблеме странное животное, страдающее протрузией верхих резцов и экзофтальмом (пучеглазостью). Таскает за собой огромный рантайм, и требует плясок для взаимодействия с GUI. Но компилируется, и иногда даже работает.

И C#. Это корпоративный монстр, который не работает без своего любимого рантайма, не работает, если у вас не та версия рантайма, и иногда работает, если все звезды сошлись и память не кончилась раньше.

Ну, есть еще какой-то там Rust, но пока что на рынке недостаточно зануд, желающих делать на нем не-helloworldы.

А ассемблер. Ассемблер - не компилируется, ассемблер - ассемблируется.

Компиляция, это что - это сборка из готовых кусков. А в ассемблере нету готовых кусков, там однозначное соответствие - инструкция - опкод.

Comment: И все, для остальных нужны интерпретаторы? Delphi, Ruby, JS

Comment: Delphi, это Паскаль. Изнасилованный Борландом, "Эмбракадаброй", или как там ее, но все же, Паскаль.
Для остальных нужен или интерпретатор, или жирнючий рантайм (Go, C#)

Comment: @gbg, добавьте в ответ, если не сложно, Go - вполне себе используется в продакшене на нагруженных проектах.

Comment: Скрипт на python можно собрать в ехе с помощью утилит

Comment: @gil9red, я об этом написал - при помощи бубна можно практически любой скрипт засунуть в экзешник. Только быстрее и экономичнее он от этого не станет.

Comment: @gbg, это точно, но ведь цель в таком случае -- переносимость, чтобы на конечной машине не пришлось ставить: интерпретатор и библиотеки

Comment: @gil9red ... и иметь на конечной машине 368 542 версии интерпретатора и 76 233 версии библиотек на каждый скрипт.

Comment: Вы еще забыли асемблер, тоже ведь "компилируемый" и для Windows и для Linux

Comment: @gbg, всегда обходился одной версией интерпретатора и библиотек, а такой зоопарк интерпретаторов и библиотек еще нужно найти :)

Comment: Эээ, а какой язык обходится без большого рантайма? Вон рантайм к C — целый Linux.

Comment: @VladD а на микроконтроллере AVR рантайм к C в килобайт влезает.

Comment: @gbg: Да, C компактный язык, вполне может и быть. (А насколько там полная поддержка стандарта языка?) Вот уже с C++ такое вряд ли прокатит: одна лишь поддержка потоков в полном объёме требует довольно серьёзного рантайма.

Comment: @VladD ну, там работают стандартные синтаксические конструкции. В любом случае, IO и работу с памятью на этих малютках приходится сооружать свои - сильная привязка к железу.

С++ на AVR прекрасно работает - Arduino назывется.

Comment: @gbg: Вангую, что он там без потоков, без std::thread, и ошибка аллокации памяти небось возвращает nullptr, а не бросает исключение?

Comment: @VladD, конечно. Исключения на таких камнях обычно сразу выключают - больно прожорливы они. А к std::thread нужно тащить скедулер, потому как операционки-то, фактически, и нет. Но куда его девать, если памяти оперативной считанные байты?

Comment: @gbg: Ну тогда, строго говоря, это не C++. Потому что C++ по стандарту включает всю (!) стандартную библиотеку. (Я ж говорил, что линукс — рантайм к C.) Без этого всего можно сделать только C-с-виртуальными-функциями, а не C++.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39108/discussion-between-gbg-and-vladd).

Comment: По крайней мере, говоря о GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection), надо добавить   Objective-C и Ada а также м.б. упомянуть, что gcc Java может быть скомпилирована прямо в native code.

Comment: @VladD, ну libc, а за ней целый Linux (или другое ядро) этот runtime у всех языков.

Comment: @avp: Угу, я именно это и говорил. Мой пойнт в том, что у C тоже большой рантайм, просто поскольку C — системный язык линукса, то там этот рантайм встроен в систему.

Comment: Вопрос задан неверное: компилировать можно в нативный код или байт-код. В исполняемый файл нужно собирать.

Answer (score 0):

Список компилируемых языков представлен  [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers). Я считаю неразумным их переписывать)

Comment: ну и вопросы я задавал 5 лет назад, аж стыдно