# Разница между компилятором и интерпретатором

Tags: компилятор, терминология, интерпретатор

Какая разница между компилятором и интерпретатором? Может ли язык программирования иметь и компилятор и интерпретатор?

Comment: [может](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html#Interpreter|outline)

Comment: Бейсик имел традиционно много разных компиляторов и интерпретаторов.

Comment: [Смотрите также](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518816/181100)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Чтобы опеределить разницу, давайте узнаем, что это такое:

> Компиля́тор — программа или техническое средство, выполняющее компиляцию.
>
> Компиля́ция — трансляция программы, составленной на исходном языке высокого уровня, в эквивалентную программу на низкоуровневом языке, близком машинному коду (абсолютный код, объектный модуль, иногда на язык ассемблера). Входной информацией для компилятора (исходный код) является описание алгоритма или программа на предметно-ориентированном языке, а на выходе компилятора — эквивалентное описание алгоритма на машинно-ориентированном языке (объектный код). [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)
>
> Интерпрета́тор — программа (разновидность транслятора), выполняющая интерпретацию.
>
> Интерпрета́ция — пооператорный (покомандный, построчный) анализ, обработка и тут же выполнение исходной программы или запроса (в отличие от компиляции, при которой программа транслируется без её выполнения). [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Таким образом, можно заключить, что компилятор преобразует исходный код к близкому к машинному коду. Интерпретатор же, позволяет выполнять некоторое представление программы, налету преобразуя в машинный код.

Если взять язык `java`, то он имеет, как компилятор, так и интерпретатор. Компилятор преобразует исходный код в байткод. А байткод в начальной стадии выполнения программы обрабатывается интерпретатором.

Компилятор, это отдельная программа `javac`, интерпретатор же встроен в `jvm`. Помимо обычного компилятора, в `jvm` присутствует `just-in-time` компиляция. т.к. интерпретация довольно медленна, то горячие места в программе компилируются в машинный код `jit` компилятором, тем самым ускоряя выполнение.

Comment: *Компилятор, это отдельная программа javac* - тут есть некоторая проблема с терминологией, потому что в jvm тоже есть сущность с названием "компилятор" http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html#C1Compiler

Comment: я дополнил ответ, указав на jit компиляторы. Согласен, есть небольшая путаница, но javac это компилятор, тут все верно https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: _Интерпретатор же, позволяет выполнять некоторое представление программы, налету преобразуя в машинный код._ Интерпретатор не выполняет преобразования "на лету", это уже рантайм-компиляция получится. Интерпретатор уже содержит готовый исполняемый код для каждой элементарной инструкции, и, прочитав очередную строку кода, он формирует цепочку вызова этих готовых исполняемых кодов и параметры для передачи им.

Comment: @Akina не совсем понял идею. Где ошибка в моих рассуждениях - байт код преобразуется интерпретатором в машинный код, который сразу же выполняется.  При этом он нигде не сохраняется. Суть моего ответа заключается именно в этой детали. Компиляция сохраняет результат работы, а интерпретация, преобразует, транслирует представление в машинный код, который следом выполняется

Comment: Скорее нет, чем да. Какая разница, выполняется компиляция всего кода или одного оператора, сохраняется на диске или нет? Разница в том, что истинный интерпретатор, в отличие от истинного компилятора, уже содержит готовые компилированные процедуры выполнения конструкций языка, и именно они выполняют требуемые действия. И в этом смысле промежуточный случай, компиляция в P-код, не является ни тем, ни другим (ну или и тем, и другим, как посмотреть) - но исторически этот вариант отнесли к компиляции.

Comment: @Akina Как то все это очень тонко, и разница почти незначительная

Answer (score 5):

1) Разница в том, что компилятор преобразует код алгоритмического языка в исполняемый (байт-код либо нативный) код (в пределе - в машинные коды), в то время как интерпретатор самостоятельно распознаёт и выполняет построчно инструкции программного кода.

2) Да, может. Даже древние turbo/quick basic - и те могли. Причём Borland Turbo BASIC был "в одном флаконе", в то время как Microsoft Quick Basic использовал, как и все современные, внешний компилятор.

**UPD:** Наверное, можно ещё сформулировать так: интерпретатор для выполнения программы обязан располагать исходным кодом программы (в исходном либо формализованном виде) на алгоритмическом языке, в то время как компиляция создаёт исполняемый модуль, который не содержит текста программы на алгоритмическом языке. Также, если при компиляции не добавляется отладочная информация, невозможно полное восстановление исходного кода.

Answer (score 3):

интерпретатор **выполняет** программу,
трансляторы в т.ч. компиляторы преобразуют без выполнения