# Компилятор и интерпретатор. В чем разница?

Tags: компилятор, интерпретатор

Да, да. Это очередной вопрос о разнице между компилятором и интерпретатором ЯП.
Только ответы, которые обычно даются меня не удовлетворяют.

Обычно говорят, компилятор переводит код на каком либо ЯП в исполняемый и уже при выполнении код сразу выполняется непосредственно процессором. В случае интерпретатора, в процессе выполнения программы специальная программа интерпретатор считывает исходный код программы построчно и выполняет его. Шаг за шагом. При этом говорится, что мол компиляторы не так-то просто еще написать.

Собственно вопрос вот в чем. Если в итоге программа выполняется, то какая в сущности разница выполняется сразу машинный код, или сначала интерпретатор что-то делает с исходным кодом, а уже потом выполняет его - в итоге-то процессор выполняет такие же инструкции машинные. Какая тогда разница? Явно же не в том, что компилятор сохраняет машинный код в файл заранее, а интерпрететор нет)
Ну допустим я понимаю, что при интерпретации программы с if-ами какая-то часть никогда может быть и не выполнена, а следовательно не переведена в машинный код. Но, опять же, наверное не в этом проблема, что сложно перевести все if-ы в машинный код заранее, то есть скомпилировать код.

Короче, в чем еще отличия и сложности реализации компилятора в отличии от интерпретатора?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606948/208074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отличий два:

1. *Интерпретатор не занимается генерацией* машинного кода. Вместо этого он вызывает для каждой интерпретируемой команды специальную функцию (являющуюся частью кода интерпретатора), которая и делают всю работу.

   Компилятор же (как обычный, так и JIT) сначала генерирует машинный код, который затем скармливается процессору для непосредственного исполнения.
2. *Компилятор делает всю работу единожды* (при сборке программы), а интерпретатор — каждый раз при чтении очередной инструкции. То есть при компилировании накладные расходы выполнения меньше, а следовательно, выше скорость работы конечного кода.

Теперь касательно сложности реализации компилятора. Интерпретатор просто берёт и выполняет очередное выражение программы; а как выполнит — тут же забывает про него (разумеется, предварительно сохранив результат). Компилятор же вынужден мыслить более глобально: тут и оптимизации, и межмодульный импорт/экспорт сущностей (ведь программа может состоять из множества файлов исходных кодов). В придачу, компилятор должен придерживаться определённых соглашений и стандартов для взаимодействия с другими инструментами (компоновщиком, к примеру); интерпретатор же является «вещью в себе», делающей всю работу самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну а когда интерпретатор берет и "просто выполняет очередное выражение" он же выполняет это на процессоре, то есть он  "знает" как эта строка на ЯП переводится в машинный код. Почему бы тогда сразу не пройтись по коду и не записать инструкции в машинном коде и потом их уже выполнять, собственно что и делает компилятор. Какая там такая сложность в реализации компоновки той же или подключении модулей?

Comment: @bayah, то, что вы описали — это уже не интерпретатор, а [JIT-компилятор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: @bayah `Какая там такая сложность в реализации компоновки...` — в наличии кучи дополнительного кода в компиляторе и необходимости знания соответствующих форматов файлов при его создании.

Comment: @bayah, `он "знает" как эта строка на ЯП переводится в машинный код` — нет, не знает. Интерпретатор, считав конструкцию программы, просто «дёргает» готовую функцию, выполняющую необходимую операцию. То есть никакого машинного кода при выполнении не генерируется.

Comment: как не знает? Ну хорошо, а функция, которую дергает интерпретатор она же знает как выполнить действие на процессоре, что и есть машинный код. А реализация этих функций ведь известна, и что в итоге нам мешает записать машинный код зная исходный?

Comment: @bayah, дёргаемая функция уже скомпилирована и является частью кода интерпретатора. То есть сам интерпретатор кодогенерацией не занимается. Как только мы начнём генерировать машинный код — получим компилятор (пусть даже JIT, но всё же). *Спасибо, кстати, за наводку, уточнил свой ответ.*

Comment: ну тогда получается, что эти самые скомпилированные функции, которые выполняют исходный код можно считать кусочками скомпилированной исходной программы, ну то есть понятно что буквально исходная программа не компилируется, а выступает как данные для этих функций, но в целом-то суть не меняется. Получается единственная разница между выполнением скомпилированной или интерпретируемой программой это просто уровень разбиения на конечные скомпилированные блоки. В интерпретаторе просто блоки крупнее и более жестко заданы изначально, на этапе написания интерпретатора. Так?

Comment: @bayah, да. Сформулировано необычно, но абсолютно верно.

Comment: @bayah Компилятор сложнее хотя бы потому, что ему как раз надо генерить машинный код, который между прочим разный у разных процессоров. Следовательно тому, кто его пишет необходимо быть экспертом в ассемблере. А для реализации интерпретатора этого не требуется, вы просто пишите обработчики для функций языка, на другом высокоуровневом языке и не задумываетесь о том, где какие инструкции конкретного камня лучше и в каком порядке оптимальнее их положить, за вас это сделает как раз компилятор

Answer (score -1):

"компилятором и интерпретатором" - не совсем корректный вопрос. Вещи абсолютно разные. Компилятор - преобразует исходный код в исполняемый (машинный, который будет исполняться процессором или какой-нибудь промежуточный, который будет исполняться виртуальной исполняющей средой). Интерпретатор же исполняем исходный код. 
Видите разницу ? Компилятор преобразует(компилирует), а интерпретатор исполняет(интерпретирует). 
Возможно вы хотели иначе поставить вопрос: в чем отличие компилируемых яп от интерпретируемых. Разница очевидна: вторые можно исполнять как есть и для это не нужно дополнительных инструментов. 
Ну в общем попробую подытожить: в конечном счете да, в конечном счете мы имеем изменение состояния процессора, реального физического процессора и к этому сводится исполнение любой программы. Но различия ведь есть:
1) компилируемые языки требуют специальных инструментов (компиляторов), конечный продукт частично защищен и сложно получить исходный код, конечный продукт более компактен , так как состоит из бинарных инструкций, а не из человеко понятных -
 слов. Конечный продукт исполняется быстрее - ибо он описан инструкция, которые напрямую поддерживаются целевой платформой. 
2) интерпретируемый язык исполняется как есть - не требует доп. инструментов для доведения до финального состояния, не защищен - любой может украсть и изменить.... 
Я понимаю, что написал очевидные вещи. Я просто не понимаю что вы вообще кроме этого хотите услышать.

Если про сложность, то компилятор и интерпретатор могут быть одинаково сложны в написании. Если язык сложный, то в любом случае его будет сложно разбирать на лексемы, не важно для какой цели для исполнения или компиляции. Ну лишь тот момент, что перед комплятором всегда будет стоять задача приведения инструкций к какой-то канонической, придуманной не вами форме

Comment: Ну если упростить, то я не понимаю в чем сложность реализовать компилятор, когда реализован интерпретатор, при очевидном преимуществе в скорости выполнения скомпилированной программы?

И как это интерпретируемый язык не требует дополнительных инструментов? А интерпретатор?)
Как по мне, так наоборот, это скомпилированная программа не требует дополнительных инструментов.
Ну это если говорить о этапе выполнения программы.