# Интерпретатор и компилятор в итоге генерируют одинаковый машинный код?

Tags: ассемблер, компилятор, интерпретатор, байткод

В моем понимании компилятор берет исходный текст программы, например,

```
A = 2;
B = 3;
print(2 + 3);
```

Компилирует его, на выходе мы получаем машинный код. Допустим, условно, получилось 3 команды:

```
1110
1101
1010
```

Далее нам уже не нужен компилятор, мы можем передавать этот скомпилированный код куда угодно (где такой же процессор) и он будет успешно выполнятся.

Интерпретатор же будет брать каждую строчку по очереди, преобразовывать в промежуточный байт-код своей виртуальной машины и потом уже виртуальная машина будет по очереди переводить свои команды в машинный код т. е. команды процессора

1. Вопрос: получится ли в итоге, что интерпретатор выполнит те же самые команды?

   ```
   1110
   1101
   1010
   ```
2. И если так, то почему никогда нельзя получить скомпилированный код интерпретируемых языков?
3. Так же, когда говорят про компиляторы, употребляют такую фразу, что компилятор выполняет программу целиком, что это значит? Ведь процессор все равно будет выполнять машинный код по очереди, по одной команде? Т. е. в итоге, что компилируемый код, что интерпретируемый будет выполнятся по одной команде, отправленной процессору?

Comment: Вообще, интерпретируемые языки тоже можно компилировать. Компилятор - штука умная, он может ещё до выполнения программы показать Вам, где есть ошибки, а интерпретатор - нет. 
Ещё, он может, например, оптимизировать Ваш код и он будет работать значительно быстрее.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Разница между компилятором и интерпретатором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606941).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Компилятор и интерпретатор. В чем разница?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671781).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Первое утверждение** не полностью верно - несмотря на то, что выполненная интерпретатором программа может фактически делать то же самое, что и ее откомпилированный аналог, грубо говоря, между иструкций откомпилированной программы появятся инструкции, обслуживающие *внутренюю кухню интерпретатора*.

Обычно интерпретатор проходит программу **по одному выражению**, это одно выражение он парсит и немедленно исполняет. **Генерации кода при этом вовсе не происходит.** Еще есть переходный вариант - это JIT-компиляция (js, java), и это уже промежуточный случай между чистым интерпретатором (BASIC) и чистым компилятором (C++)

**Второй подвопрос** - иногда можно, если сузить число возможных действий. Так, [KPHP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPHP) позволяет транспилировать программу на PHP в код на C++.

Самый мощный пример, почему программу на транслируемом языке не всегда можно откомпилировать - во многих языках есть `eval()` - функция, которая исполняет строку на этом языке. Таким образом, придется в откомпилированную программу внедрить полностью весь интерпретатор.

Далее, из откомпилированной программы удаляется очень много всего - имена переменных, функций, информация о типах. Иногда то что написано в виде класса с методами сдувается до пары машинных инструкций - так что компиляция программы с интерпретируемого языка не приносит пользы - оптимизация (ради которой приходися терпеть неудобства C++) становится невозможной.

Никогда не слышал о том, что **компилятор что-то выполняет "целиком"**. Компилятор проходит программу (иногда не один раз), после чего создает двоичный код сразу для всей единицы трансляции.

Comment: по 3) возможно не правильно понял.
А в чем тогда разница JIT-компиляции от интерпретации. Я правильно понимаю что интерпретатор на последнем шаге своей работы переводит свой внутренний байткод все равно в машинный код. Вроде тем же самым занимается JIT-компилятор?

Comment: Интерпретатор как раз и отличается тем, что ничего в машинный код не переводит - не все интерпретаторы даже переводят программу в байткод, им достаточно разбра по выражениям.

Comment: все таки не совсем понимаю. А как в итоге код интерпретатора выполняется если он не переводится в итоге в машинный код?

Comment: В интерпретаторе написано буквально:

if(cmd == "add") { cout << a+b;} else
if(cmd == "sub") { cout << a-b;} else
...

Никакого перевода в машинный код не нужно

Comment: это понятно, я имею ввиду что в итоге код { cout << a+b;} все равно же преобразуется в машинный и попадёт на процессор. И в таком случае не совсем понятна тогда разница jit-компилятора которые берет некий последний уровень и переводит в машинный код и некий последний уровень интерпретатора который выполняет { cout << a+b;} тоже фактически переводя в машинный код в итоге же?

Comment: На момент трансляции программы, код cout << a+b; уже давно преобразован в машинный код, транслятор просто запускает его на выполнение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123390/discussion-between-gbg-and--).

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрим случай, когда вы даете **компилятору** на вход программу на языке программирования высокого уровня. Он вам на выходе даст программу на языке ассемблера. В виде исполняемого файла, объектного файла или может просто вывести на экран ассемблерный код. Это не важно, ведь задача компилятора состоит только в том, чтобы перевести программу с языка высокого уровня на язык ассемблера. Это как переводчик с русского на английский.

В случае, когда вы **интерпретатору** даете на вход программу на языке программирования высокого уровня интерпретатор вам никакой другой программы на выходе не дает, он *исполняет* ту программу, которую вы ему передали. *Как* он ее исполняет — не важно. Он может делать с ней все, что хочет: может переводить в байт-код и исполнять на виртуальной машине; может ничего никуда не переводить и сразу ходить по AST<sup>*</sup> и его выполнять; может переводить в нативный код (ассемблер) и исполнять уже его. Вот последний случай, когда интерпретатор переводит код в нативные инструкции процессора, называется **JIT-компиляцией**<sup>‡</sup>.

Можно заметить, что компилятор программу не выполняет, он просто ее переводит с одного языка на другой. А вот интерпретатор программу выполняет, а переводит он ее во что-то или нет — не важно, это его личное дело.

---

Касательно ваших вопросов:

1. Не обязательно, главное чтобы наблюдаемое поведение программы оставалось таким же. Вы можете написать разные инструкции, которые в итоге будут делать то же самое.
2. Почему нельзя, можно. Можно, например, [получить](https://blog.mozilla.org/attack-and-defense/2020/09/15/inspecting-just-in-time-compiled-javascript/) результат JIT-компиляции кода на JavaScript.
3. «*… употребляют такую фразу что компилятор выполняет программу целиком…*», ни разу такого не слышал, да вы и сами теперь знаете, что компилятор ничего не выполняет. «*Т.е. в итоге что компилируемый код что интерпретируемый будет выполнятся по 1 команде отправленной процессору?*» Да, в итоге все программы, которые выполняются на вашем компьютере, выполняются вашим процессором инструкция-за-инструкцией<sup>†</sup>. Только в случае интерпретируемых программ это происходит не на прямую, а через посредника — интерпретатор.

---

Для примера напишем интерпретатор простого языка, в котором будут три оператора: увеличить счетчик `+`, уменьшить счетчик `-` и вывести счетчик `@`. Вся программа представляет из себя строку из этих трех символов.

Вот так может выглядеть интерпретатор этого языка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static unsigned int counter = 0;

void increment_counter(void) { counter++;               }
void decrement_counter(void) { counter--;               }
void     print_counter(void) { printf("%u\n", counter); }

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Наша программа предается как первый аргумент командной строки. */
    char *source = argv[1];

    /* Проходим по всем символами нашей программы (операторам). */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        const char operator = source[i];

        /* Смотрим, что у нас за текущий оператор и выполняем его. */
        if (operator == '+')
            increment_counter();
        else if (operator == '-')
            decrement_counter();
        else if (operator == '@')
            print_counter();
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что никакого перевода из нашего языка в язык ассемблера не происходит. Когда наш интерпретатор встречает оператор `+` он просто вызывает некоторую функцию, которая делает некоторые вещи, в данном случае — увеличивает счетчик.

То есть интерпретатор понял, что мы хотели получить, ничего переводить в ассемблер не стал и просто сам выполнил все, что было нужно.

---

* <sup>Это называется tree-walk интерпретация.</sup>

† <sup>Ну, если не брать в расчет всякие микроархитектурные детали типа параллелизма на уровне инструкций.</sup>

‡ <sup>Например, существует JVM HotSpot. Она при исполнении программы находит такие места программного кода, которые выполняются часто и занимают много процессорного времени и компилирует их в нативные инструкции процессора, чтобы такие места (они называются [хот-спотами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))) выполнялись быстрее. Это пример техники JIT-компиляции, компиляции «на лету».</sup>

Comment: Спасибо! А я правильно понимаю что интерпретатор в итоге так или иначе все равно преобразует/выполняет каждую строчку в машинный коде все равно? В чем тогда разница интерпретатора и JIT-компиляции что jit кеширует/оптимизирует некоторые участки за счёт компиляции предварительной? Но суть в итоге одинаковая и там и там так или иначе на выходе машинный код все равно?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, ну вы сами можете написать, например, на Си интерпретатор какого-нибудь простого выдуманного вами языка. Вы будете просто читать код программы построчно и вызывать ту или иную Си-функцию, чтобы его выполнить. Ни о каком машинном коде речи идти даже не будет.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, сам интерпретатор не обязан ничего преобразовывать. Он может взглянуть на исходный код вашей программы, увидеть, что там написано `a + b` и выполнить это. Он не будет преобразовывать `a + b` в машинный код, он просто *поймет*, что вы хотите сделать и сделает. Это как если бы я был переводчиком с китайского на русский и какой-нибудь китаец попросил какого-нибудь русского налить ему чай. Я бы не стал ничего переводить, а просто налил чай сам. Я вам советую написать интерпретатор языка Brainfuck, пишется буквально за пару часов, получите много опыта.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо это понятно. Но я имею ввиду что после того как интерпретатор понял что я хочу сделать он же это выполнит тоже на каком то языке который тоже в процессе выполнения должен будет преобразован в машинные инструкции?

Comment: @КириллМалышев да эту часть я понимаю. Вопрос что дальше происходит.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, сейчас я напишу небольшой интерпретатор в ответ, надеюсь, это прояснит этот момент.

Comment: @eanmos я смотрел примеры простых интерпретаторов и понял их принцип. Т.е. я правильно понимаю что если мы переводим код с условного нового языка если у нас нет JIT-компиляции мы просто поняли что нужно сделать а=1+2 и выполним такой код на Си который в свою очередь отправит нужные команды на процессор если мы на Си разработали наш инерпретатор. Если же есть jit то мы этот код не будем выполнять на Си а получис непосредственно машинный код и отправим на процессор.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, точно, все верно :)

Comment: @eanmos да, я почему то совсем упустил тот момент что сам интерпретатор это скомпилированная программа в которой инструкция "counter++" уже скомпилирована в машинный код, а интерпретатор просто по исходному тексту нашего нового языка как бы выбирает какую инструкцию вызвать.